# iPhone Debugging Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 907

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.2

Created an app for adhoc distribution and installed on iphone but it is not working on the installed iphone,Tried connecting the iphone to mac and debug the app but it throws up error stating

" Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process
907."

is there a way to debug the adhoc distribution provision file from xcode

Answer (score 10):

No, you can't debug an AdHoc build in XCode--setting `get-task-allow` to FALSE in your Entitlements.plist basically says "don't allow the debugger to connect to this", and is required for AdHoc and AppStore builds.

See

[What does get-task-allow do in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003066/what-does-get-task-allow-do-in-xcode)

or the documentation...

Answer (score 5):

I started having this error in my projects in XCode 4.2, and had a tough time figuring it out with the new project layout.

Make sure you go into the Project Settings and change the Code Signing Identity to a development profile for the Debug setting in the *target* settings.  It's a bit easy to miss because the Project settings come up first, and there are identical looking Code Signing Identity settings there.  But Target settings trump Project settings.

If that still doesn't work in XCode 4.2, go to "Edit Schemes" - in the project drop down, which is just to the right of the stop button, in the left segment of that custom pop-up.  Select "Run" and make sure Build Configuration is set to "Debug".

In prior versions of XCode, it used to tell you whether you were in debug or release right up front; I haven't found where it's that obvious with the new "Schemes".

Answer (score 2):

Restarting the xcode worked fine for me