# iPhone Development - Running apps on device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am trying to run the app on my device and there seems to be a problem with the code signing entity. If I choose the developer profile in the code signing entity, it runs fine but if I choose the distribution profile (I've tried both the Adhoc and Appstore distribution) it says "Build Succeeded" but it gives a popup error message saying -

```
Error Starting Executable “App Name : Device Name”
Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 3273
```

Am I supposed to see this or am I doing something wrong again ? 
Thanks

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182249/iphone-debugging-error-launching-remote-program-failed-to-get-the-task-for-proc) your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not test and run the application with distribution profile at your end. The distribution profile is just for signing the project ipa  and upload it to the app store. For running onto your device, only developer profile will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test application on device, then you need to create debug profile for it. You need to get it for your device from the provisioning section of developer portal. If you are creating the distribution profile, then you need to put the generated ipa file from build folder to itunes to install it on device.

Then you can install the application on device. But in that case you will not be able to see the logs.

So if you want to see the logs in Xcode console, Create a developer provisioning profile for the device & install it on XCode & then run the code on device using Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the entitlements.plist problem please follow the steps

In XCode, go to "new file" and select "code signing" in left box. Select the "Entitlements" file type. And change the name to "Entitlements.plist". Give the name in project getinfo entitlements plist please check the image below
[image]