# Error installing iOS app with Ad Hoc Profile

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have finished developing a big  and heavy app. It is universal (for iPhone and iPad), and now I am  trying to publish it in App Store. I have done this other times, so I  know how annoying it is.

I'm using Xcode 4.2 and devices with many iOS  versions (4.2.1, 5.0, 5.1). My app is enabled to send Push  Notifications, and it doesn't use iCloud.

I  have tested it with development certificate, and it works OK. Now I've  generated and downloaded Ad Hoc Distribution Provisioning Profile in  order to test it in my iPhone and iPad. It seem like all is OK, but when  I'm going to install the app (with the Ad Hoc Distribution Provisioning  profile) with Xcode in any device, Xcode shows an error: "Error  launching remote program: failed to get the task for process".

I've read [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1682/_index.html) link it suggests two causes:

- I am using Ad Hoc Distribution Provisioning profile when debugging the  app in my device. This is not the problem, because I'm not debugging the  app.
- I specify a code signing entitlements property list in my build  settings which does not include a "get-task-allow" or "Can be debugged"  property. This is not the problem, because I'm not specifying any  entitlements property list because I don't need it (or I think so).

Some people that have the same problem solve it  adding the "get-task-allow" property to the entitlements property list.  But I haven't that file. So the question is, Do I need to create it just  for add the "get-task-allow" property?

If I don't , which is the problem? I'm not trying to debugging and I haven't entitlements p-list in my app.

Although  my app doesn't need entitlements p-list, I tried to create it and add  the "get-task-allow" property in OFF following [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1710/_index.html), but it didn't solve the problem.

I have also to say that althought Xcode shows  the error during the installation in the device and the app shut off,  when I start again the app, the installation is done and the app runs  without problem.

I read the following similar thread, but they didn't solve my problem:

- [iPhone Debugging: How to resolve 'failed to get the task for process'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488600/iphone-debugging-how-to-resolve-failed-to-get-the-task-for-process)
- [Profile bug (Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process XXX.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720597/profile-bug-error-launching-remote-program-failed-to-get-the-task-for-process)
- [iPhone Debugging Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 907](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182249/iphone-debugging-error-launching-remote-program-failed-to-get-the-task-for-proc)
- [Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 699](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959645/error-launching-remote-program-failed-to-get-the-task-for-process-699)

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using Ad Hoc Distribution Provisioning profile when debugging the app in my device. This is not the problem, because I'm not debugging the app.

This is exactly the problem.
You are trying to run an ad-hoc application from the XCode - it means to debug it.

You should archive your app and install it (an ipa file) together with the correct provisioning profile.

There are few ways to install the app:

- Using iTunes - not trivial
- Using an iPhone Configuration Utility - easier
- Using some OTA (over the air) installation service (e.g. TestFlight site) - I use this all the time, after a couple of times it gets really easy and you can distribute your Beta version to remote devices (e.g. clients, friends etc.)

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I was wrong  about the app behabiour.

Answer (score 0):

The problem look like you are running App from Xcode with Ad Hoc Distribution Provisioning profile.

After Archiving (Product menu > Archive ) the App from Xcode, you can get ipa.

1. You can install ipa via iTunes if you device already sync with your iTunes app.
2. https://testflightapp.com/ , I am using testflightapp for testing the app. It's easy to use and we can distribute to for test user.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I was wrong  about the app behabiour.