# Understanding Entitlements.plist for iPhone projects

Tags: iphone, debugging, plist, entitlements

I have some query regarding Entitlements.plist. According to the Apple documentation

We can use iOS capabilities using Entitlements.plist. There is only one public entitlement key  available named 'Can be Debugged'/get-task-allow that adds debugging capability.

I have not added Entitlements.plist to my project of my app and I am able to debug my app running on the device.

Could someone help in understanding

a) What is Entitlements.plist and
b) Why is it required?

Answer (score 0):

"Can be Debugged'/get-task-allow" is the flag which is need to be set "NO" during the development/debug proces, and "YES" when we need adHoc/distribution build. By the default - it's is "NO", that's why you can run your app on the debug device (using "development" provision file). But you not be able to build you app for ad Hoc or Distribution without Entitlements.plist.

Comment: I am confused little: According to me during development process we need to debug and hence 'Can be Debugged' should be set to YES; for Adhoc we should not allow debugging and hence it should be set to NO. So, during development don't I need this plist?

Comment: here You can find the discusion on this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003066/what-does-get-task-allow-do-in-xcode