# Distribution provisioning profile doesn't include the get-task-allow entitlement

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, xcode8

In my project I have three targets - project target, unit test target and UI test target.

While upgrading to Xcode 8 I am facing issue with UI test target with error message:

> Provisioning profile doesn't include the get-task-allow entitlement.

The image below shows my problem.

[image]

**How to workaround this?**

However there is a mismatch between that alert and what is there indeed:

[image]

Comment: Check answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003066/what-does-get-task-allow-do-in-xcode

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, the solution was that I included get-task-allow in my entitlements file as well as my provisioning profile. Remove it from the entitlements file to fix this issue.

Comment: how did you add the get-task allow in entitlements file??

Comment: Remove get-task-allow in the entitlements file and just allow it in the capabilities tab.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any instances of get-task-allow in an entitlements file? If so, try removing it. It will get automatically copied into the app's entitlements when signing is performed.