# Ad Hoc distribution fails

Tags: ios, itunes, distribution

I get this on the iOS device logger after iTunes fails to install.
I'll be happy for some help.

```
May  5 22:09:05 unknown installd[849] <Error>: entitlement 'get-task-allow' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
May  5 22:09:05 unknown installd[849] <Error>: 00381000 verify_signer_identity: Could not copy validate signature: -402620394
May  5 22:09:05 unknown installd[849] <Error>: 00381000 preflight_application_install: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.ZPtjaK/foo_extracted/Payload/BaBus.app
May  5 22:09:05 unknown installd[849] <Error>: 00381000 install_application: Could not preflight application install
May  5 22:09:05 unknown SpringBoard[52] <Notice>: Posting 'com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus' notifyState=1
May  5 22:09:05 unknown UserEventAgent[12] <Warning>: DEBUG: Changing screen blanked state: 0
May  5 22:09:05 unknown SpringBoard[52] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 255->0 (deferring until bootloaded)
May  5 22:09:05 unknown SpringBoard[52] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: device bootloaded
May  5 22:09:05 unknown SpringBoard[52] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 0->0
May  5 22:09:06 unknown installd[849] <Error>: 00381000 handle_install: API failed
May  5 22:09:06 unknown installd[849] <Error>: 00381000 send_message: failed to send mach message of 71 bytes: 10000003
May  5 22:09:06 unknown installd[849] <Error>: 00381000 send_error: Could not send error response to client
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess this project or provisioning profile has some parts that predate Xcode4.

Somewhere you have `get-task-allow` entitlement set to true, and it needs to be set to false. Per [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1026124), that was needed to allow other processes like debugger to attach; but it's not allowed for ad hoc distribution.

But in XCode 4, you don't really need to set entitlements at all. From the [release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TROUBLESHOOTING_GUIDE-CODE_SIGNING_ENTITLEMENTS) (emphasis mine)

> **I'm defining a custom Code Signing Entitlements file in Xcode but do I need it?**
>
> If you are defining a custom Code Signing Entitlements file within your Target > Build Settings, you might try removing that configuration entirely and rebuilding/resubmitting. More often than not, Code Signing Entitlements are defined unnecessarily. You only need to specify a custom Code Signing Entitlements file if your application is utilizing custom keychain access sharing or iCloud. Otherwise, remove the Code Signing Entitlements configuration from all build configurations on your Xcode project's Target > Build Settings, the rebuild and reattempt your submission/validation.
>
> ...
>
> *If you are unsure whether you need to define a Code Signing Entitlements file, it is safest to remove the configuration from your Target > Build Settings until you know for sure its need*.