# iOS app 'The application could not be verified'

Tags: ios, xcode

When I am running my app on iPhone5(the only device I have) iOS 8.3 it gives an error 'The application Installation Failed.' App is running in simulator without any problem. Using XCode version 6.2.

I have added a valid valid provisioning for my app and my device UDID has been added to provisioning profile.

What may be the issue. Struck on this since 3 hours.

**EDIT:**

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997884/application-could-not-be-verified-error-when-building-app-for-iphone-device), but none of answers solve my issue.

Comment: update ur xcode version]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application could not be verified error when building app for iPhone device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997884/application-could-not-be-verified-error-when-building-app-for-iphone-device)

Comment: there may be many reason for this failure.. lot's of people has asked this question on SO. check your provisioning profile is having the details of your device, your device is not having already the app installed...etc

Comment: @dasdom I have checked that link, that does not solve the problem

Comment: @Kalpesh ok i will do that, but my other applications are working fine on the this version of xcode

Comment: @Iftikhar I have re-added a new provisioning profile and my device UDID is registered with provisioning profile

Comment: then as suggested by @Kalpesh update your xcode

Answer (score 1):

Here is the steps i used to get rid of this error

1. Delete the app from the device
2. Restart xCode
3. Clean
4. Build & Run